# CupertinoPageRoute shifting content upwards when pushing to a new page

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been developing an app and noticed that the CupertinoPageRoute keeps pushing content upwards when going to a new page. This is quite annoying as it creates a lag/stutter effect.

Here is an image demonstrating this issue:
[Incorrect UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnoS.png)

Meanwhile this is how the UI is supposed to look:
[Correct UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7inH.png)

Here is a video:
https://vimeo.com/798133261

My code:

```
 WelcomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController emailEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome!",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Text(
                    "Sign up to see what your friends are listening to!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 100),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/app/app_icon_transparent.png',
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ThirdPartySignIn(),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                        child: CupertinoButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              CupertinoPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SignupPage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                colors: [
                                  CustomColors.accentColor,
                                  CustomColors.accentColor
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign up",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: headlineLabelFontSize,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: CupertinoColors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At first, I thought that the issue was with the Stack widget, however I tried using a column widget and recieved the same effect. I am not sure if this is a bug but I am sure that there is a possible work around. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, I just had to add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to my main scaffold, and the page stopped resizing.